# ¿Qué significa "tuanis"?

Tags: definiciones, significado

¿Cuál es el significado de la palabra *tuanis*? ¿Se escribe *tuani* o *tuanis*? ¿En cuáles regiones se usa? Y, ¿es una palabra muy informal, o se puede usarla en otros contextos también?

Comment: Try http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tuanis

Comment: "Tuani" es del escaliche o malespín.

Se usa en Costa Rica porque hace más o menos 60 años en este país había una gran influencia de la cultura nica.

Comment: Solo a manera de ilustración. En Costa Rica, utilizamos coloquialmente, tuanis, no tuani. Saludos

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Es la primera vez que oigo esta palabra (soy de España). Según la RAE es una palabra coloquial (no vulgar) que se usa por centroamérica (según la RAE, en el Salvador, Honduras y Nicaragua) para decir que algo es de calidad o está de moda.

> tuanis.
>       1. adj. coloq. El Salv. y Hond. Dicho de una cosa: De excelente calidad.
>       2. adj. coloq. Hond. Dicho de una cosa: Que está de moda.
>       3. adv. m. coloq. Hond. bien (‖ según es debido).

La propia RAE muestra que es correcto escribir tuani también, aunque parece que esta forma es más común en Nicaragua.

> tuani.
>      1. adj. El Salv. y Nic. Dicho de una cosa: tuanis (‖ de excelente calidad).

A ver si algún nativo de estos países lo puede confirmar.

Comment: Nicaragüense acá confirmo lo dicho, que tuani tu respuesta! :D

Comment: La usamos en Nicaragua con mucha frecuencia para resaltar que algo es grandioso , super o positivo. Por ejemplo: Que tuani estaba la pelicula!,  que tuani sos!

Comment: +1 a todos por haberme hecho aprender una nueva palabra. Ahora solo falta ver si algún lingüista entre el respetable público nos quisiera explicar de dónde viene tan sabroso término.

Comment: Curioso tanto la respuesta de @Miguel como la de `Emilio Noruega`. Personalmente solo había escuchado este [tema musical](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRYOzgdiRO8) _(aunque dista de ser una fuente oficial)._ Por las características del video, supuse que la expresión sería de origen centroamericano. +1 para ambas respuestas.

Comment: puedes dar un ejemplo frasal.

Answer (score 21):

La palabra TUANI proviene del [alfabeto creado por el General Malespín](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malesp%C3%ADn) durante la intervención de Estados Unidos en Nicaragua en 1912, en ese entonces el General Benjamin Zeledón le encomendó al Gral. Malespín que creara un alfabeto especial para poder enviar y recibir mensajes sin que los gringos pudieran descifrarlo.

El alfabeto consistía en cambiar algunas letras por otras; por ejemplo con las vocales; A por E y la E por A, la I por O y la O por I, la letra U quedo igual, en cuanto a las consonantes, la B por T y la T por B, la C por S y la S por C, la M por P y la P por M, la F por G y la G por F.

De manera que la palabra TUANI es el resultado de la palabra BUENO es decir:

> T U A N I = B U E N O

En Nicaragua existen otras palabras también usadas pero menos común como por ejemplo EPOFI que significa AMIGO, BRETEJI que es TRABAJO, HARPENI es HERMANO y PENEFUE que significa MANAGUA.

Comment: Esta es una respuesta muy interesante, así que me he permitido añadir un enlace para respaldar el contenido del mismo. Buen trabajo! Bienvenido a Spanish.SE. Espero seguir viendo respuestas tuyas tan buenas como esta en el futuro.

Comment: El general Malespín llevaba casi setenta años muerto cuando ocurrió la intervención estadounidense. Como dice el enlace, existe la tradición de que este alfabeto lo inventó él, pero en el siglo XIX.

Answer (score 3):

En Guatemala, **tuanis** se escucha bastante, principalmente entre niños y jóvenes.  Es una manera coloquial, no vulgar, de expresar que algo es de muy buena calidad, o que uno personalmente está muy bien.  Expresiones usadas en forma similar son **virgo** o **bien de a huevo**, aunque la última talvez si es considerada algo vulgar.

Answer (score 2):

Palabra del lenguaje propio de Nicaragua que surge en las carceles de Leon en tiempos del dictador Anastasio Somoza Debayle y que significa literalmente bueno...

Answer (score 2):

La expresión "tuanis" viene de las palabras inglesas "too nice": "demasiado bonito"
y es usada para decir que algo es muy bueno, muy agradable o de muy buena calidad.

Es muy usada en Centro América, principalmente en Costa Rica.

Answer (score 0):

Tuanis lo usamos en Costa Rica, y tengo la teoría de que proviene del inglés de la frase "too nice" que ésta se pronuncia "tú nais" por ende al escucharla se interpretó "tuanis"
Esta frase la usamos para calificar algo bueno, como un sinónimo de bonito, bello, lindo etc.
Se dice que cuando una palabra que en este caso es un regionalismo, se usa y se unifica en una sola voz, la lengua española debe integrarla al diccionario como una palabra válida y real!

Comment: David, bienvenido al foro. Por favor revisa las reglas del foro. Esa pregunta fue respondida hace más de un año y la respuesta estaba debidamente documentada. Una de las reglas de ese foro es tratar en lo posible de no dar respuestas basadas en opiniones personales. Esperamos contar con tus aportes y ayudar a resolver tus dudas sobre el Español en el futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Yo oía esta palabra en Costa Rica hace años.  Yo creía que significaba la palabra inglesa "twenties," como los billetes de veinte dólares.  Yo siempre la entendía como, “I feel as good as twenty bucks!”  (*Yo me siento tan bueno como un billete de veinte dólares*).

Answer (score 0):

En Honduras la usan pero solo personas que han cogido calle en vez de estudios. Sin embargo siempre uno que otro de vez en cuando se le escapa la palabra pero ya no es tan tan popular o frecuente, solo utilizada por vagos.
Preferimos decir "Todo pinta, ¡Qué Pinta!", "Todo Cheque" o "Macanudo mae" y otras expresiones un poco más toscas como "Pijudo" que significa "Bueno, Excelente" igual que las antes menicionadas.

Answer (score 0):

Soy hondureño y tuani para nosotros significa chao, adios, bye  solo en honduras se inventó eso en el Salvador no se dice eso, para cuando se despidan de un amigo un hondureño digale tuani

Answer (score 0):

En El Salvador la palabra "tuanis" significa "bonito" o "bueno". Es mayormente usada por los jóvenes.

Answer (score -1):

Codigo Maliche

• A = E
• I = O
• B = T
• F = G
• P = M

T = B;
U = U;
A = E;
N = N;
I   = O;
S  = S;

Parónimo

P = M;
E = A;
L = L;
I  = O;
S = S;

Comment: Los [cifrados de sustitución](http://www.dma.fi.upm.es/recursos/aplicaciones/matematica_discreta/web/aritmetica_modular/cesar.html) como este o el clásico César son muy fáciles de romper mediante el análisis de las frecuencias de los caracteres. Por eso dejaron de usarse hacia el siglo XVI.

Comment: excelente, viene a corroborar lo dicho [en otra respuesta de 2015](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10795/1674)

Comment: Bienvenido Rodolfo. Ten en cuenta que las respuestas deben agregar algo diferente a las respuestas anteriores. Esto se respondió hace 6 años y en tu respuesta no se agrega información adicional.  Pásate por el [help center](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help) y sigue contribuyendo. Nuevamente bienvenido